# Candidate Elimination, a special use case

Tags: machine-learning

So I'm understanding and learning the candidate elimination process, to find the hypothesis space. I am a little confused with running the CEl on the following example:

We have a cage in which two birds can live in the same cage. Each bird is described with

- sex (Male, Female)
- Color (Red, Green, Blue)
- Origin ( US, Brazil, Russia, Australia, China)

After some iterations I have the **S** Specific hypothesis and **G** General Hypothesis as follows:

**S** << Male, Red, ?>, < Female, Blue, China>>

**G** << ?,?,?,?>, < ?,?,?,?>>

Now if the training example is:
**Negative i.e. can't live together** << Female, Red, US>, < Female, Blue, Australia>>

What will be the new **G** General hypothesis?

Let me write what I believe could be the answers:

**New G**

**Either:**
<< Male, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, ?>> &&
<< ?, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, China>>

**Or:**
<< Male, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, ?>> &&
<< ?, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, China>> &&
<< ?, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, Russia>> &&
<< ?, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, Brazil>> &&
<< ?, ?, ?>, < ?, ?, US>>

I think 2nd one is correct, because its a general hypothesis and it should be general to include the rest of three countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is incorrect because according to the Candidate Elimination Algorithm, for each minimal specialization of **G**, there must be an hypothesis in **S** that is more specific.  But you have added three specializations for which the single hypothesis in **S** is not more specific (**S** requires the second bird to be from China, whereas the last three specializations you added to **G** require other specific countries).

The first version appears correct.

Note that there is an assumption here that the order of two birds in the hypothesis matters.

Comment: nicely explained! yes the assumption is that order matters.